# How do I assign numerical values to characters in a column in R?

Tags: r

I have imported a table (.cvs) in R, which has a column for income, where the income is given as either `<=50K` or `>50K`.

```
>str(hausuebung_daten$income)
 chr [1:500] "<=50K" "<=50K" ">50K" "<=50K" ">50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" ">50K" "<=50K" ">50K" ">50K" ...
```

Now I am trying to convert this column from character to numeric. I have been able to convert it to factor

```
> hausuebung_daten$income<-factor(hausuebung_daten$income)
> str(hausuebung_daten$income)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "<=50K",">50K": 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
```

And then tried assigning the factors a numerical value (using the plyr package)

```
library(plyr)
> hausuebung_daten$income<-revalue(hausuebung_daten$income, "1"="<=50000", "2"=>"50000")
Error: unexpected '>' in "hausuebung_daten$income<-revalue(hausuebung_daten$income, "1"="<=50000", "2"=>"
```

and I get the error message as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse()` to do this since you are only messing with `"<=50K"` and `">50K"`.

```r
hausuebung_daten$income <- ifelse(hausuebung_daten$income == ">50K", 2, 1)
```

```
> hausuebung_daten$income
 [1] "<=50K" "<=50K" ">50K"  "<=50K" ">50K"  "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K"
 [9] ">50K"  "<=50K" ">50K"  ">50K" 
> hausuebung_daten$income <- ifelse(hausuebung_daten$income == ">50K", 2, 1)
> hausuebung_daten$income
 [1] 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following might be something for your purpose:

```
hausuebung_daten$income <- factor(hausuebung_daten$income,labels = c(1,2))
```